# None of the methods in RemoteViewsFactory is getting called at all

Tags: android, android-widget, remoteview, android-remoteview

I have tried my best to follow the directions on [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html) but seems like I have a stupid error somewhere that I cannot figure out.

After continuous logging, I realized that none of the methods run in my implementation of the RemoteViewsFactory that (tries to) set ListView in a widget with the data from a content provider cursor.

*RemoteViewsFactory*:

```
private Context context;
private int appWidgetId;
private Cursor cursor;

public FootballScoreFactory(Context context, Intent intent){
    this.context = context;
    appWidgetId = intent.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);

}

@Override
public void onDataSetChanged() {

    if(cursor != null){
        cursor.close();
    }

    String[] date = new String[1];
    Date filterDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    date[0] = format.format(filterDate);
    try {
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
                Uri.parse([content uri here, tested, returns the data]),
                null,
                null,
                date,
                null
        );
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
@Override
public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {

    String leagueName, home, away, homeGoal, awayGoal;
    leagueName = home = away = homeGoal = awayGoal = "";

    if(cursor.moveToPosition(position)){
        leagueName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseContract.scores_table.LEAGUE_COL));
        home = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseContract.scores_table.HOME_COL));
        away = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseContract.scores_table.AWAY_COL));
        homeGoal = String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseContract.scores_table.HOME_GOALS_COL)));
        awayGoal = String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseContract.scores_table.AWAY_GOALS_COL)));
    }

    RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_list_item);
    rv.setTextViewText(R.id.league_name, leagueName);
    rv.setTextViewText(R.id.home, home);
    rv.setTextViewText(R.id.away, away);
    rv.setTextViewText(R.id.home_score, homeGoal.contentEquals("-1")? "-" : homeGoal);
    rv.setTextViewText(R.id.away_score, awayGoal.contentEquals("-1")? "-" : awayGoal);
    return rv;
}
```

*RemoteViewsService*:

```
@Override
public RemoteViewsFactory onGetViewFactory(Intent intent) {
    return new FootballScoreFactory(getApplicationContext(), intent);
}
```

*AppWidgetProvider:*

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
    for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, FootballScoreService.class);
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));

        RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.football_score);
        rv.setRemoteAdapter(appWidgetId, R.id.widget_list_view, intent);
        rv.setEmptyView(R.id.widget_list_view, R.id.empty_view);

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, rv);
    }

    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);

}
```

Any help as to what I need to do to make sure that the views are updated would be awesome. If it helps, the `rv.setEmptyView(...);` seems to be working at all times.

And the biggest heartbreak I got in this is when I thought I had NOT bound the views in app manifest file but it looks like I did. :(

```
<service android:name=".FootballScoreService"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_REMOTEVIEWS" />
```

Answer (score 4):

So, turns out I figured out my own problem. It was as simple as my RemoteViewsFactory not returning the correct value for getViewTypeCount(). I left it at 0 at first. When I changed it to 1, it worked.

Go on, laugh at me. I did. Hopefully this helps some poor <del>sole</del> soul like myself at some point.

I would not be surprised if I stumble across this again lol.

Comment: Actually i have to say this is rather confusing in the API, as the is no getItemViewType method. And I just stumbled upon a case where i had only 4 viewTypes, but kept getting a log entry that i would return more viewTypes the getViewTypeCount suggests. So I randomly added +1 and now it works. So it seems to me that the actual viewType is guessed by the Launcher/Android and if you do heavy modifications to a RemoteViews instance it will detect it as a new viewType...